# linq query distinct date

Tags: c#, linq

On the query below how can remove de time part of the datetime column to get only the distinct dates?

```
using (var ctx = new DBConn())
{
  var q = ctx.Table.Select(r => r.datetimefield).Distinct();
}
```

Comment: This question has the correct answer, you want to use EntityFunctions.TruncateTime
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11524853/distinct-date-with-linq

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are stumbling over a fault with linq-to-sql or EF (I don't know which one you are using). The straight forward solution would be to use the `DateTime.Date` property, however, this is unsupported in both ORMs, it doesn't map to an SQL method.

You have two solutions:

1. eager evaluation of the query by using `ToList`:

   ```
   var q = ctx.Table.ToList().Select(r => r.datetimefield.Date).Distinct();
   ```
2. create a field detailing only the date component in the database. This is the way I usually go as you can stay in the database and execute the query there.

Comment: yeah, you need `Value` if `datetimefield` is a `Nullable<DateTime>`. Be aware though that this will push the query into memory which can take a long time for extensive queries. You should have a look into point two, it will save you a lot of headaches in the long run.

Comment: Actually, there is a way to do it, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11525054/68818

Answer (score 4):

Assuming `r.datetimefield` is a DateTime, you can use [`DateTime.Date`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx) to remove the time component:

```
var q = ctx.Table.Select(r => r.datetimefield.Date).Distinct();
```

Comment: You can't, at least not with linq-to-sql or EF as the `Date` property doesn't map to an SQL method.

Comment: The date property is available throught value.date but I get the error "The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities"

Comment: yes, that's what I'm hinting at. You can't use the `Date` property in a query as EF doesn't map it to an SQL method. Which I personally see as a massive fault.