# Distinct Date with Linq 

Tags: c#, linq, datetime, linq-to-entities, distinct

I have an entity called Billings with a property of DateTime. I need to uniquely find the dates so I can go through them and do some stuff.
I tried:

```
var DistinctYearMonthsDays = (from t in db.Billings 
                              where t.DateTime.HasValue 
                              select   t.DateTime.Value.Date).Distinct();

foreach (var day in DistinctYearMonthsDays)
```

but I get (on the `foreach`):

> The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.
>   Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties
>   are supported.

After searching I also tried the following without success:

```
IEnumerable<DateTime> DistinctYearMonthsDays = db.Billings
    .Select(p => new 
        {              
            p.DateTime.Value.Date.Year,
            p.DateTime.Value.Date.Month,
            p.DateTime.Value.Date.Day 
         }).Distinct()
         .ToList()
         .Select(x => new DateTime(x.Year,x.Month,x.Day));
```

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Have you had a look at [this][1] page?



  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289338/linq-query-distinct-date

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the built in EntityFunctions. Your query would become:

```
var DistinctYearMonthsDays = (from t in db.Billings 
                              where t.DateTime.HasValue 
                              select EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(t.DateTime)).Distinct();
```

For more about EntityFunctions, check [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738563.aspx).